# How to 9 slice meshes?

Tags: unity

So let us assume I have a 3D model of a window and I would like to stretch it like a 9 sliced sprite. How would you go by doing 9 slice on meshes? All I found online was about quads. What about more complicated meshes?

Comment: What prevents you from writing a vertex shader to scale specific regions of the mesh differently?

Comment: Cyan used a form of this they called "Stretchables" in building Obduction - [you can see them describe it starting around 21 minutes into this GDC Vault video](https://gdcvault.com/play/1023211/Building-Obduction-Cyan-s-Custom). In their case it looks like an edit-time feature: they bake two sets of UVs in the mesh, one that stretches with the mesh, and one that tiles at a fixed frequency. Then their shader uses the stretched maps to add edge-aware shape detail to the tiling texture of the base map.

Comment: I've just made a tutorial showing one method of doing this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ExNRbEjVT-8

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is not as popular as 9-slicing images, so it doesn't come with popular engines.

Having said that, you can always do this manually. Editing a mesh is easier than editing an image, so it's not difficult to separate a mesh into 9 pieces (like you would an image) and either scale the in-between meshes, or tile them, or a combination of both. You don't have to mess with shaders or anything complicated, just the basic transformations of a 3D object are enough.

The process is the same as when using an image, and maybe you can do a "27-slice" if you want the same effect on 3D.

Comment: How come defining few planes and passing it to the shader is complicated?

Comment: @Ocelot some programmers are not familiar enough to be comfortable using shaders. A question of "how to do 9-slice with meshes" hints to me that the OP might not be that experienced, so I provided a beginner-friendly answer. If I was wrong, and OP is experienced with shaders, then other users viewing this question could benefit from it instead. In both cases, OP can solve their problem.

Comment: @Ocelot care to write an answer?

Comment: So Tom you are saying, I slice the mesh then scale the mesh in the center?

Comment: @JoeRobert I don't use Unity

Comment: @JoeRobert You can view Unity's documentation of how 9-sliced images are made [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/9SliceSprites.html). Basically you can do the same thing with a mesh, divine it in 9 pieces, where the corners stay as they are, and the in-between pieces fill the rest of the space. Either by being scaled, or by tilling them next to each other, both ways would work, so its up to you.

Comment: @TomTsagk Is 27 slicing equivalent to 9 slicing?

Comment: @JoeRobert Yes, it's like doing 9 slicing on 3 different meshes (front, middle and back) of a 3D object. The implementation makes no difference if you do it manually.

Comment: @TomTsagk Ah so for 3D models you must slice in the front, back and middle?

Comment: @JoeRobert It doesn't matter how you do it, think of a 3D object like a Rubic's Cube, 9x9x9 pieces, where the middle pieces stretch and the corners remain as-is. There is no one way to do it, any way you choose would work.